# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Помогите! Нужна ли запятая перед как в такой фразе "Желаю любви как в кино"

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна, сравнительный оборот "как в кино" входит в основное сообщение. Оборот играет роль несогласованного определения, то есть "желаю особенной любви".

Answer (score 0):

Здесь запятая будет нужна, если речь идет о каком-то конкретном кино - такое тоже вполне возможно.
Собственно, мне кажется, тут можно поставить запятую, а можно и не ставить, как написано в первом ответе, - ошибки не будет.

Comment: Думаю, что при постановке запятой ошибка будет. Чтобы поставить запятую, нужно изменить предложение:"Желаю такой любви,  как в кино". Иначе можно подумать, что любовь бывает только в кино.